# School management System database architecture

Tags: database, architecture, multiple-databases

I have started working on a School Management System for learning purposes.

Now I am using only mongoDB database, but I am thinking about a clean architecture on this project so I want to hear some suggestions from you.

I want to divide all the data to handle a big traffic in the fastest way.

I have the following modules in my app:

1. auth system
2. user types
3. subjects
4. classes
5. marks
6. absences
7. schedule
8. forum
9. chat (with sockets)

I thought to keep the first 8 points mentioned above in MySql and I am thinking about the chat to use RabbiMQ and mongo with caching in Redis.

**1.** What would be the difference between **RabbiMQ and mongo with caching in Redis** and using **cassandra with RabbitMQ** for chat?

**2.** What would be the best solution to handle a big traffic for chat?

**3.** If you would architect this app in another way, how would you do it and why it would be better than the way mentioned above?

Thank you!